# Unable to connect via Remmina both computers Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: remote-desktop, remmina

I've got two computers running Ubuntu 16.04.  I'd like to use one of them, my laptop, to have full remote desktop access to the desktop when I'm traveling.  I figured I'd start with connecting while I have them both on the same WiFi network at the house.

On the desktop:

[image]

and I'm using `ifconfig` to find the internal IP Address by choosing the value of `inet addr:` under `wlan0`.

And on the laptop, I've started Remmina and created a new connection.  I have the following configuration:

Name: movies
Protocol: VNC - Virtual Network Computing
Server: I've tried both the internal IP Address I described finding above, and the same IP with a `:5900` at the end
Password: same password I entered in the above screenshot

When I hit `Connect`, I just get a `Connecting to 'movies'` dialog and it is just stuck here.

I've run `ps -e|grep vino` on the desktop and see a `vino-server` there so it seems like there is a server running

I'd like to be able to control the desktop computer with the laptop.  What else can I try to get Remmina to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a first step have you tried disabling firewall?
sudo ufw disable

Then try and see if you get same results.
If you connect and issue is resolved, then you need to know what ports your program uses and make a simple firewall rule and re-enable firewall and test again to see if issue is resolved.

Comment: That worked, thanks so much!  How do I `know what ports your program uses and make a simple firewall rule and re-enable firewall`?

Comment: Okay `sudo ufw allow 5900` did the trick, hopefully that's not terribly insecure?

Comment: No, it is fine. Standard stuff. You could always use a different uncommon port number if you feel a bit worried about it.